# Get the column index of a row in grid on click of button added on topbar in extjs

Tags: ext.net

How can I get all the columns by index. Like I don't know how many columns I have and what is their DataIndex value then how to get them.

Actually I want to clear the cells so thats why looking for indexes of each column in row. If there is any other way to clear the row data then please help in that.
Currently I have got the row index by using below code,

> var record = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
>
> var index = store.indexOf(record);

now first thing i want to do is to clear the contents of cells in selected row on clicking button and secondly i want to get index of the columns inside this selected row and set any value to them using their index.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you actually want to change something if a specific value in a cell appears - to do that in your grid add:

```
 <View>
     <ext:GridView runat="server" >
             <GetRowClass Fn="getRowClass" />
     </ext:GridView>
</View>
```

and in the `getRowClass` you then can do what you want for each row like:

```
function getRowClass(record) {
    var someVar = record.data.<columnIndex>;
    if (someVar == <someValue>) {
       do something
    }}
```

Comment: I think you did not check the title of question. Sorry but this is not what i wanted. I just wanted to know that How can I get the Index of columns on click of BUTTON on toolbar. Currently I am using click handler to call a function in which I am getting the selected row and its index. Now I just wanted to know the code for getting number of columns and the column index. If you could continue the code with my above mentioned code then It would be helpful for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Buttons' Handlers.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!X.IsAjaxRequest)
        {
            Store store = this.GridPanel1.GetStore();
            store.DataSource = new object[] 
            { 
                new object[] { "test1", "test2", "test3" },
                new object[] { "test4", "test5", "test6" },
                new object[] { "test7", "test8", "test9" }
            };
        }
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET v2 Example</title>

    <script>
        var setRecord = function (record, value) {
            var i,
                fields = record.fields.items,
                field;

            record.beginEdit();

            for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                field = fields[i].name;

                if (field !== record.idProperty) {
                    record.set(field, value);
                }
            }

            record.endEdit();
        };

        var clear = function () {
            var grid = App.GridPanel1,
                selection = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection(),
                i;

            for (i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
                setRecord(selection[i], "");
            }
        };

        var set = function () {
            var grid = App.GridPanel1,
                selection = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection(),
                i;

            for (i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
                setRecord(selection[i], "new");
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

        <ext:Button runat="server" Text="Clear" Handler="clear" />

        <ext:Button runat="server" Text="Set" Handler="set" />

        <ext:GridPanel ID="GridPanel1" runat="server">
            <Store>
                <ext:Store runat="server">
                    <Model>
                        <ext:Model runat="server">
                            <Fields>
                                <ext:ModelField Name="test1" />
                                <ext:ModelField Name="test2" />
                                <ext:ModelField Name="test3" />
                            </Fields>
                        </ext:Model>
                    </Model>
                </ext:Store>
            </Store>
            <ColumnModel runat="server">
                <Columns>
                    <ext:Column runat="server" Text="Test1" DataIndex="test1" />
                    <ext:Column runat="server" Text="Test2" DataIndex="test2" />
                    <ext:Column runat="server" Text="Test3" DataIndex="test3" />
                </Columns>
            </ColumnModel>
        </ext:GridPanel>        
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```